# Anyone see a mistake with my Reset function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, reset

alright, I have made a function to clear two text boxes on the click of a button. For some reason that I dont know it isnt working. Code is pasted below -

```js
 function clear() {

            document.getElementById("IMEI").value = "";

            document.getElementById("Command").value = "";

        }
```

```html
<!-- IMEI -->

        <label><font color=#829DBA face="Tahoma"><b>IMEI:</b></font></label>

        <input type="text" name="ID" id="IMEI" maxlength="15">

        <!-- -->


        <!-- AT Command -->

        <label><font color=#829DBA face="Tahoma"><b>AT Command:</b></font></label>

        <input id="Command" type="text">

        <!-- -->
 
<!-- Clear Button -->

    <button type="button" onclick="clear();">Clear</button>

    <!-- -->
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a scoping issue with the word `clear`, change the function name to `cleared` and you will see it working correctly. You could also call the function with `window.clear()` if you were unable to rename this function for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

At the font-tag is a bug: color attribute needs quotes.

```js
 function clear() {

            document.getElementById("IMEI").value = "";

            document.getElementById("Command").value = "";

        }
```

```html
<!-- IMEI -->

        <label><font color="#829DBA" face="Tahoma"><b>IMEI:</b></font></label>

        <input type="text" name="ID" id="IMEI" maxlength="15">

        <!-- -->


        <!-- AT Command -->

        <label><font color="#829DBA" face="Tahoma"><b>AT Command:</b></font></label>

        <input id="Command" type="text">

        <!-- -->
 
<!-- Clear Button -->

    <button type="button" onclick="clear();">Clear</button>

    <!-- -->
```